# Showing Ads on Certain Scenes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sprite-kit, admob

I am making an iOS game with SpriteKit and have just implemented adMob (linked to Firebase). However, after following the steps provided by Google and adding code into the ViewController, it shows the ads on all the scenes, like the Main Menu Scene, Game Scene and Game Over Scene. I would like the banner ad to only be displayed on the Main Menu and Game Over Scene.

Below is the code that I have in the GameViewController:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

var bannerView: GADBannerView!
var admobBanner = UIView()

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Advertisments
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())

    admobBanner = bannerView
    //

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'MainMenuScene.sks'
        if let scene = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill //change back to aspectFill if experiencing problems

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

//Advertisments
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints([NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0), NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)])
}
```

Later, to hide the advertisements on the GameScene I put this code in the DidMoveToView of the GameScene:

```
admobBanner.removeFromSuperview()
```

This works to hide the banner ad on the game scene, but it does not get re-enabled in the other scenes. How do I "re-enable" it in the MainMenu and GameOver Scene? I tried doing this to re-enable the advertisements in the MainMenu and GameOver Scene, but it did not work (errors and warning have been shown as comments):

```
func showBanner(){
    if admobBanner == nil { //WARNING: Comparing non-optional value of type 'UIView' to nil always returns false

        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner) 
        addBannerViewToView(bannerView) //ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier 'addBannerViewToView'
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self //ERROR: Cannot assign value of type 'MainMenuScene' to type 'UIViewController?'
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())

        admobBanner = bannerView
    }
}
```

So, the question is, how do I show banner ads on certain scenes and hide them on others? Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle all the banner stuff in the `GameViewController.swift` file. Inside there, assign a tag value for the `bannerView` variable. Then when the scene loads, load the `bannerView` using the tag id, then set its `.isHidden` property to `true`.

GameViewController.swift

```
bannerView.tag = 100
```

Game.swift

```
// hide banner
let bannerView = self.view?.viewWithTag(100) as! GADBannerView?
bannerView?.isHidden = true
```

You can do that on other Scenes too, just make sure to import the Google SDK for each scene your doing it on.